# Rental - how to repair shower frame cleaned with bleach in error

Tags: bathroom, repair, shower, bathroom-fixtures

I made a big mistake today when cleaning the shower. I used bleach on the frame, which I think is fibreglass but I'm not sure. As you can see from the pictures it appears to have taken the coating off it and has discoloured it badly.

I am in a rented property so this is a big concern. I need to try and fix this myself or do something else.

Can this be fixed? If so, what do I do and buy? I thought the frame may be fibreglass but the first comment on Imgur said it isn't?...

https://imgur.com/gallery/t9x5q

Comment: Are you sure the track is not aluminum? Maybe you removed anodizing. Or maybe this is a residue and *not* removal of a coating. Pour a small amount of boiling water in an inconspicuous spot and rub with a rag. Any improvement?

Comment: You may be right, it could be aluminium. What is anodizing and can it be replaced/fixed? It got worse after taking a shower and having water run over it. I will try with boiling water in the morning but if it is lost anodizing then what can I do? What are my options to repair? I'm worried it's only going to get worse the more water hits it.

Comment: Anodizing is a process which allows controlled thickening of the natural oxide coating on aluminum. I think that bleach is commonly used to kill mold in showers and I'm surprised that the finish on the shower track was damaged by it, however, most people use spray like Tilex or equivalent which must be less concentrated than Clorox. Did you put concentrated chlorine bleach right out of the bottle on it? Does the apartment complex give any guidance on what cleaning products are to be used to clean the shower track?

Comment: I retract my suggestion to use boiling water. This could cause damage. You don't want to cause more damage. It might be best to just let the apartment management decide what to do. They may have seen this before and have worked out a procedure.